# Overlapping Times Calulation in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have Downtime table with columns: Service Id, Start Time,End Time. I need to calculate Downtime in minutes, excluding the overlapping times.
To give example:

| Service | StartTime | EndTime | Downtime Minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SERVICE-1 | 20-04-2023 10:00:00 | 20-04-2023 10:20:00 | 0 |
| SERVICE-1 | 20-04-2023 10:10:00 | 20-04-2023 10:25:00 | 0 |
| SERVICE-1 | 20-04-2023 10:20:00 | 20-04-2023 10:30:00 | 30 |
| SERVICE-1 | 20-04-2023 11:10:00 | 20-04-2023 11:15:00 | 5 |
| SERVICE-1 | 20-04-2023 13:00:00 | 20-04-2023 13:10:00 | 10 |

If we see above data, rows 1,2,3 times overlap. So the final calculated time is 30 min, 4th and 5th rows do not have any overlaps so the outputs are 5min and 10min.

How to write a sql query for this?

Comment: Your final result is only row 3. That means the time is more than 30 minutes,can you show expect result with text?

Comment: I have Service, Start Time, End Time columns, so the Downtime minutes is what needs to be calculated output. But I cannot just put that. This way it's easier to explain.

Final Output is the sum of values in Downtime Minutes column for that service

Comment: you should write a query and show what you already tried, you must chck the LAG entime with the start time and make something like a gap and island

Comment: result final is 45 minute? can you show expect result with text?

Comment: if max(prevEndTime)>=StartTime`select service,starttime,endtime,case when lead(starttime) over(partition by service, grp order by starttime,endtime) is null then datediff(minute, min(starttime) over(partition by service, grp), max(endtime) over(partition by service, grp)) end
from (select *, sum(add1) over(partition by service order by starttime,endtime rows unbounded preceding) as grp from (select *, case when starttime <= max(endtime) over(partition by service order by starttime,endtime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
 then 0 else 1 end as add1
from downtime) as r) as g`

Answer (score 2):

```
with grouped_downtimes as (
  select service, starttime, endtime, 
         sum(marker) over (partition by service order by starttime) grp
  from (
    select case when lag(endtime) over (partition by service order by starttime)
                   > starttime then 0 else 1  
           end marker, service, starttime, endtime
    from downtime) m )
select service, starttime, endtime,
       case row_number() over (partition by service, grp order by endtime desc) 
       when 1 then 
          datediff(mi, min(starttime) over (partition by service, grp),
                       max(endtime) over (partition by service, grp)) 
       end downtime
from grouped_downtimes
order by service, starttime
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qndgt9AN)

Use lead or lag to assign markers 1 when period not overlaps with previous row, 0 otherwise. Then analytic sum to group these markers into... groups. Then you can find min starttime and max endtime and count datediff.
I also used rownumber to show downtime in last row per group.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is to group the overlap time periods and then calculate the downtime for a group. There are many solutions available and below are some articles that you can refer. Test the solutions in your scenario for performance.

1. [SQL Queries for Overlapping Time Periods on SQL Server](https://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-query-for-overlapping-time-periods-on-sql-server.aspx)
2. [Calculating Gaps Between Overlapping Time Intervals in SQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/calculating-gaps-between-overlapping-time-intervals-in-sql/)

A more in-depth read on the subject can be available [Interval Queries in SQL Server](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/interval-queries-sql-server)